# How to access images directory outside of the Asp.Net Core Project

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I'm trying to serve images from a directory outside of the current ASP.NET Core 6 project that I'm working with and none of the images are showing. I've read the [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-6.0) and some of the other SO posts. So I kinda understand what needs to happen, I just don't know if I'm doing this right.

Program.cs

```
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions()
{
  FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.GetFullPath("C:\\Development\\Website\\Classic\\websiteImages\\Images\\ItemImages")),     
});
```

in the View I call the image like so

```
 <img src="@Url.Content(@pic.FileLocation +"\\"+ @pic.FileName)" />
```

and I've tried it this way as well

```
 <img src="@pic.FileLocation\@pic.FileName" alt="@pic.FileName" width="100" class="img-thumbnail d-inline">
```

This is the `@pic.FileLocation` path: "C:\Development\Website\Classic\websiteImages\Images\ItemImages"

and  `@pic.FileName` is something coming from the Database like `10001234.jpg`

If I copy and past the image path into a browser tab it shows the image, so I know the image is there.

Here is what the `src` looks like in the browser.

[image]

Comment: Is the image path correct when you view source from the browser?

Comment: You should probably set `StaticFileOptions.RequestPath` to a subfolder to ensure that you can't have a picture with the same name as any other endpoint of your site.

Comment: @JonP yes I see an Image when I view source path in another browser tab. If thats what you mean.

Comment: No, the page itself. When sent to the bowser. View Source for the page. What is the `src` attribute?

Comment: @JonP i have an image in the original question of what it looks like.

Answer (score 1):

What do you get for the img's `src` attribute after the `@Url.Content()` call? That is, what address is actually rendered to the browser as part of the final html?

If the address still starts with `C:\Development`, something isn't right. The address in the image element's `src` attribute resolves from the perspective of the user's browser, not your web server, so it needs to look something more like this:

```
https://example.com/classic-site/websiteImages/Images/ItemImages/10001234.jpg
```

Then in your application, if the the classic site is no longer online on it's own you need to able to receive a request for that address and map to the right place so it serves the right file.

You have to be careful testing this, because very often during development the server and browser run on the same computer. In that scenario, an address like `C:\Development\Website...` might **seem** to work just fine in the web browser, but it will fail as soon as you start hosting the application on it's own server, away from the end user's browser.

Comment: posted an snapshot of what the `src` looks like in the browser.

Comment: @whish yeah, that's the wrong result. As said, you need to have a web URL here, not a local file system address.

Comment: i guess that's were I lost and dont know how to set the path then.

Comment: Remember: images are retrieved via their own separate http requests. You may need a new route in your app (something like "ClassicImages") so you can write a web url to refer to these images. The route can accept these requests and return the image data from the correct local path.

Answer (score 1):

Since you've already configured the statifiles middleware to provide files from that specific folder, this should work:

```xml
 <img src="~/10001234.jpg" />
```

So as long as you generate URLs in this form: `~/{fileName}` you should be good.

Here is the main documentation on serving files outside of the project folder structure:

- [Static files in ASP.NET Core - Serve files outside of web root](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-7.0#serve-files-outside-of-web-root)

Comment: so I'm trying to access files from outside of the given project. not just the wwwroot folder.

Comment: @whisk and that's exactly what is described in the article and my answer. When you configure the StaticFiles with an external path, it will be able to see those files when searching from the `~/` root, because that is a _virtual_ root and not a physical one.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you want to access cat.jpg from external , create a directory like "my static files at the same level with 'wwwroot' and then put your static contents inside it like below:

```
wwwroot
 css
 images
 js
MyStaticFiles
 images
  cat.jpg
```

Then Update the Program.cs like this:

```
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
{
    FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
           Path.Combine(builder.Environment.ContentRootPath, "MyStaticFiles")),
    RequestPath = "/StaticFiles"
});
```

Now you can access your file with this address:

https://hostname.com/StaticFiles/images/cat.jpg

which serves the cat.jpg

**Important note: if you don't add the first app.UseStaticFiles() the contents of wwwroot folder will be get ignored.**

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `app.UseStaticFiles();` because you have already `app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions() ...` and then Try this:-

```
<img src="~/@pic.FileName" alt="@pic.FileName" width="100" class="img-thumbnail d-inline">
```

Hope it will resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Save your images on WebRootPath (wwwroot folder) and then use this code on startup. Here I have two sub folder on wwwroot folder, and my request path is images.
So I can access my image on 'siteurl/images/image_file_name'. For more, you can visit this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-7.0)

```
 app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
 {
     FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(env.WebRootPath, "Temp", "Uploads")),
     RequestPath = "/images"
 });
```